# WinRT Passing ViewModel between pages

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have a two page Windows 8 application.  A view page and a settings page.  Both pages use the same view model.  I can pass the view model between pages to work with it, but then I can not save state because I have passed a complex type between pages (it has to do with how they keep references, and stops you from saving).

So I guess I need to save and reload my view model on each page?  I can't find a good reference on what is a best practice for this.

Answer (score 2):

Usually WinRT navigates through Root frame, which initialized in App.cs. It is better to define a Frame object in MainPage and navigate all your pages within this frame. Your frame datacontext can bind to ViewModel.

Comment: This was the answer.  I was setting my data context to the page instead of the static frame.  Then I just save and load it in app.cs and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx) to save ViewModel state between page navigation. I have a similar situation in an app I'm writing (same viewmodel for different pages) and it works perfectly. It'll even cache pages for you.

I [blogged](https://web.archive.org/web/20130309004944/http://thoughts.kaylynbogle.com/winrt-c-passing-parameters-to-a-viewmodel/) about using Frame with ViewModels recently, but it's more about setting up frame interaction than navigation/caching behavior.